# How to solve POST 400 {bad Request} ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm following a MERN Stack course & I'm quite new, in that I'm keeping backend & frontend codes separately.
when I trying to POST a request through frontend I'm getting an error as below screenshot, but when I trying that same POST request through backend using Postman I'm able passing the value to my MongoDB database. I couldn't find any code error on this. I'm stacked here almost 3 weeks please help me on this.
I tried to call backend both ways as below but the result is same.
`${API}/category/create/${userId}`
and
`${API}category/create/${userId}`
**please note I'm able to see my backend error message as well.**
--------------------------------------------
screenshot : [image]
--------------------------------------------
**Backend API call file | Frontend**

```
import { API } from "../../backend"

// category call
export const createCategory = (userId, token, category) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/category/create/${userId}`, {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "appliction/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(category)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

// get all categories
export const getCategories = () => {
    return fetch(`${API}/categories`, {
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

// Product calls
export const createProduct = (userId, token, product) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/product/create/${userId}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: product
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

// get all products
export const getProducts = () => {
    return fetch(`${API}/products`, {
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

// delete a product
// get a product
export const getProduct= () => {
    return fetch(`${API}/product`)
}
// update a product
```

**View file | Backend**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Base from "../core/Base";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth/helper";
import { createCategory } from "./helper/adminapicall";

const AddCategory = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const { user, token } = isAutheticated();

  const goBack = () => (
    <div className="mt-3">
      <Link className="btn btn-sm btn-success mb-3" to="/admin/dashboard">
        Admin Home
      </Link>
    </div>
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setError("");
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    setSuccess(false);

    //backend call fired
    createCategory(user._id, token, {name}).then(data => {
      if (data.error) {
        setError(true);
      } else {
        setError("");
        setSuccess(true);
      }
    })
  };

  const myCategoryFrom = () => (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <p className="lead">Enter the category</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control my-3"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={name}
          required
          autoFocus
          placeholder="For Ex. Summer"
        />
        <button onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-outline-info">
          Create Category
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );

  return (
    <Base
      title="Create a category here"
      description="Add a new category for new T-shirts"
      className="container bg-info p-4 "
    >
      <div className="row bg-white rounded">
        <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          {myCategoryFrom()}
          {goBack()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Base>
  );
};

export default AddCategory;
```

**Controller file [create category] | Backend**

```
const Category = require('../models/category');

exports.getCategoryById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    
    Category.findById(id).exec((err, cate) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Category is Not found in the Databse"
            });
        }
        req.category = cate;
        next();
    });
};

exports.createCategory = (req, res) => {
    const category = new Category(req.body);
    category.save((err,category) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Not able to save Category in to the Database"
            });
        }
        res.json({ category });
    });
};

exports.getCategory = (req,res) => {
    return res.json(req.category)
}

exports.getAllCategory = (req,res) => {
    Category.find().exec((err,categories) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "No Categories found"
            })
        }
        res.json(categories);
    });
};

exports.updateCategory = (req, res) => {
  const category = req.category;
  category.name = req.body.name;

  category.save((err, updatedCategory) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Failed to update category"
      });
    }
    res.json(updatedCategory);
  });
};

exports.removeCategory = (req, res) => {
    const category = req.category;

    category.remove((err, category) => {
        if(err){
            return res.satus(400).json({
                error: "Failed to Delete this Category"
            })
        }
        res.json({
            message: "Successfull Deleted"
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Your content type is set to `"Content-Type": "appliction/json",`, could that be it?

Comment: In the `createCategory` controller, can you log the value of `req.body` and `err`, then share their values here. Also, it would be helpful if you can post the Schema for the `Category` model.